# Eclipse Maven release plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, release

I'm trying to generate a release with goal release:prepare, but when I run it on Eclipse I got the error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0-beta-7:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project mwframework: Can't run goal clean verify:
>   Error while executing process. Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory
>   "/home/gnng/Development/work-7-maven/mwframework"):
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

I'm using Eclipse Maven Embedded, what I doing wrong?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe I am asking the obvious, but did you check that directory does exist?

Comment: Yeah, thats my workspace, I think plugin is trying to execute "mvn" from my computer and not from my Eclipse, I don't have Maven installed on my Ubuntu, just the Eclipse Embedded Maven. Should I install maven on my computer too?

Comment: The problem is that plugin is trying to run an external MVN instead of Embedded MVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maven release plugin always fork a child Maven build. So, you need to use external Maven installation (e.g. configure it in Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks Eugene, after installing an External Maven, plugin work properly.